# How can I remove the black of some of the tile textures

Tags: python, pygame

So my program is a treasure hunt game that uses a collection of tiles for the game map and on these tiles I use PNG photos for the texture, however when using PNG photos that don't fully occupy a tile, black covers the rest of the tile. I am just wondering how can you remove the black and place one texture file on top of another.

```
import pygame, sys
import random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.display.set_caption('My first game')

#colours
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
brown = (153, 76, 0)
blue  = (0, 0, 255)
grey  = (192,192,192)

#game dimensions
tilesize = 20
mapwidth = 30
mapheight = 20


coins = 0
ship = 1
water = 2
rock = 3
movesMade = 4

#dictionary for texture of the map
textures = { #the transform function scales the photo to the tile size
    ship : pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('ship.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    water: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('water.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    rock: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('rock.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    coins: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('chest.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    movesMade: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('player.png'), (tilesize, tilesize))
    }

inventory = {
    coins: 0,
    ship: 0,
    rock: 0,
    movesMade: 0
    }

#image that will represent player
PLAYER = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('player.png'), (tilesize, tilesize))

#position of the player
playerPos = [0,0]

resources = [coins, movesMade]

#utilise list comprehension to create grid
tilemap = [[water for w in range(mapwidth)] for h in range(mapheight)]

pygame.init()

#set up display
displaysurf = pygame.display.set_mode((mapwidth*tilesize,mapheight*tilesize + 60))

invfont = pygame.font.Font('FreeSansBold.ttf', 18)

#loops through each row
for rw in range(mapheight):
    for cl in range(mapwidth):
        randomnumber = random.randint(0,15)
        if randomnumber == 0 or randomnumber == 1:
            tile = rock
        elif randomnumber == 2 or randomnumber == 3 :
            tile = ship
        else:
            tile = water
        #sets position in the grid
        tilemap[rw][cl] = tile

while True:
    #user events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT and playerPos[0] < mapwidth - 1:
                playerPos[0] += 1
            if event.key == K_LEFT and playerPos[0] > 0:
                playerPos[0] -= 1
            if event.key == K_UP and playerPos[1] > 0:
                playerPos[1] -= 1
            if event.key == K_DOWN and playerPos[1] < mapheight -1:
                playerPos[1] += 1
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]
                if currentTile == rock:
                    p = 10
                    while p > 0:
                        ran1 = random.randint(0,p)
                        if ran1 % 2 == 0:
                            inventory[coins] == inventory[coins] - inventory[coins]
                            p = p - 1
                        else:
                            p = p - 1

                elif currentTile == ship:
                    inventory[coins] += 50
                    inventory[movesMade] += 1

    #loops through each row 
    for row in range(mapheight):
        #loops through each column in row
        for column in range(mapwidth):
            displaysurf.blit(textures[tilemap[row][column]], (column*tilesize,row*tilesize))

    displaysurf.blit(PLAYER,(playerPos[0]*tilesize,playerPos[1]*tilesize))

    placePosition = 10
    for item in resources:
        displaysurf.blit(textures[item],(placePosition, mapheight*tilesize + 20))
        placePosition += 30
        #text displays amount of coin
        textObj = invfont.render(str(inventory[item]), True, white, black)
        displaysurf.blit(textObj,(placePosition, mapheight*tilesize + 20))
        placePosition += 50

    #if inventory[coins] > 100:
    #    break
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that the black part of a texture appears black, then you have to [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) the surface and then set the transparent colorkey by [`set_colorkey()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey).

Befor this can be done, pygame has to be initialized by `pygame.init()` and the video mode has been set by `pygame.display.set_mode`:

```py
textures = { #the transform function scales the photo to the tile size
    ship : pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('ship.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    water: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('water.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    rock: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('rock.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    coins: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('chest.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    movesMade: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('player.png'), (tilesize, tilesize))
    }

PLAYER = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('player.png'), (tilesize, tilesize))

# [...]

pygame.init()
displaysurf = pygame.display.set_mode((mapwidth*tilesize,mapheight*tilesize + 60))

PLAYER = PLAYER.convert()
PLAYER.set_colorkey(black)

for k in (coins, ship, water, rock, movesMade):
    textures[k] = textures[k].convert()
    textures[k].set_colorkey(black)
```

Comment: I keep on getting this error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'convert'

Comment: @J.Peggy - Check you haven't set `PLAYER` to something else (i.e. a number) before calling `PLAYER.convert()`.  Rabbid76's code is correct.

Comment: @J.Peggy There is no different between player and other surfaces.

Comment: Yes there is since the other surfaces have values assigned to them in the dictionary while the player does not.

Comment: Are you searching for `textures[ship] = textures[ship].convert()` `textures[ship].set_colorkey(black)`!?!?